# Divi Landing page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using divi theme to create my website. Now at my web-address, there is a default Divi layout, when I click to customize it, Divi theme builder does not show up. And whenever I try to create new page, the theme builder appears. Help me to solve this problem so I can customize the default page using divi theme builder.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Divi -> Theme Options -> Builder -> Advanced and Enable Classic Editor.

This will disable the block editor and give you the option to use the Divi Editor on existing pages and Divi Builder on new pages

Answer (score 0):

With the latest WP Version you have Code Blocks enabled by Default, you need to Disable it then set default theme editor as Divi Theme Builder.
Note: The Divi new theme has some critical bugs and it can also be a reason for your Issue if the above statement didn't help you.

Comment: _"The Divi new theme has some critical bugs"_ sounds like your personal impression; or is there a list of those bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go to Divi > Theme Options > Builder > Advanced and Enable Classic Editor.

If that won't works then, you can try the Classic Editor Plugin from here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go to Settings > Reading and make sure to have "A Static Page" option selected.

Also, check in the "Divi Theme Builder" (Divi > Theme Builder) if you have a Body Template existing.